# Changing the control template in search results

Tags: search-results

I am wanting to replace the default control template for search results with the one that I created. My search results page is fixed in a display template too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property on the Search Results web part that allows you to change the Control Template. You can copy and alter the Out of the Box template and change the template in the Web part properties.